# Exporting SQL Server data (fixed length) to an SFTP server on a daily basis

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, scripting, sftp

Hey guys, I do most of my work in MySQL, but have recently been tasked to do some database work on SQL Server. I realize the databases work in a very similar fashion.

My task is simple, export data from a SQL Server 2008 database as a fixed length file to a secure ftp server on a daily basis.

If I was using php I would probably just write a php script that does this with a cron job. But in this case, I dont have access to any of that.  From what I read it seems like I can use SQL Server 2008 itself to do this for me.

Can anyone give any pointers and let me know if this is an easy task.  I don't want to take on a job that is beyond my skill set ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every SQL Server installation (including Express editions) comes with little tool called [bcp.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx) (Bulk Copy utility). It supports two formats, native and character. You are probably interested in the character format, see [Using Character Format to Import or Export Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190919.aspx). Adding a comma `,` field terminator will produce a CSV file:

```
bcp database.dbo.table out datafile.csv -c -t, -T
```

If you want a fixed length output, then probably the best solution is to specify a format file. See [Specifying Data Formats for Compatibility by Using bcp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190759.aspx).

Once you have the file, you can copy it to your SFTP server. The equivalent of cron on Windows platforms is the Scheduler, see [The Task Scheduler](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742545.aspx).

There are more fancier solutions, like using SSIS as Eugene suggested, which would give you more power and control. SSIS comes with SQL Server (but not with Express Edition) and on non-Express  Editions you have the [SQL Server Agent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189237.aspx) to help you schedule tasks.

Comment: so i would use the task scheduler and create a task to run bpc.exe (with some commands) to generate the file, then create another task in scheduler to take this file and stick it on a remote sftp.  it is as simple as this?

Comment: I would package the entire taks in a .cmd file and schedule that as a task.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use SQL Server Integration Services, take a look at [SFTP task](http://www.eldos.com/bizcrypto/ssis-sftp-connection-task.php) in our BizCrypto product. With integration services you can build a file and transfer it to the remote SFTP server.

Comment: This looks to be a $1000 product.  I dont think I have a budget provided for this.  You are saying SFTP transfers cannot be done through SQL Server itself?

Comment: @Roeland: SSIS is part of SQL Server itself and all editions but Express. Are you using SQL Server Express Edition for your task?

Comment: @Roeland As Remus has mentioned in his answer below, you can run some external SFTP client on schedule. Also there exist other SSIS tasks for SFTP, but I don't remember any free ones.

Comment: we are not using express from what I have been told.